# What is the correct HTTP status code to return in `res.redirect` after a successful post operation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on an ExpressJS app, after I a successful post to the end point `/api/threads/{board}` I want to redirect to the page `/b/{board}`, however I don't know which HTTP status code I need to return in `res.redirect()`. I looked at `3xx` redirection status codes on https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3 but neither one seems to fit into my case. Should I stick with `201` for a successful post operation?

Comment: 3xx codes are for redirection; [the documented default](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect) is 302.

Comment: Why not keep the sever simple & let the client to redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Redirects to the URL derived from the specified path, with specified status, a positive integer that corresponds to an HTTP status code. If not specified, status defaults to “302 “Found”. Link http codes: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

1. Redirects can be a fully-qualified URL for redirecting to a different site:

res.redirect('http://google.com')

2. Redirects can be relative to the root of the host name. For example, if the application is on http://example.com/admin/post/new, the following would redirect to the URL http://example.com/admin:

res.redirect('/admin')

3. Redirects can be relative to the current URL. For example, from http://example.com/blog/admin/ (notice the trailing slash), the following would redirect to the URL http://example.com/blog/admin/post/new.

res.redirect('post/new')

You can refer this documentation for better clarity : http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.redirect

Answer (score 1):

Yes I believe it's `201`. From MDN:

> 201 Created The request has succeeded and a new resource has been
>   created as a result. This is typically the response sent after POST
>   requests, or some PUT requests.

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Successful_responses

Although, `302` is the standard status code for redirection, note that you can only use one status code at a time since `headers cannot be set once they are sent`.

Comment: So if I do a redirection without specifying the status code, it'll default to `302`?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case.

Comment: "Moved Temporarily" for the status code `302`, doesn't fit into my case, `201` makes more sense

Comment: Yes, it does. Although there is another way you can use the status code 201 and redirect with status code 302, using a custom middleware. @matrixersp